# Mongodb ORM for Django 1.5 and Python 3

Tags: django, mongodb, python-3.x

As I searched all famous Django ORM libraries for Mongodb aren't compatible with Python 3.
Is it any compatible?

https://www.djangopackages.com/search/?q=mongodb

Comment: 1) http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html 2) why would you want ORM features on a non relational database? maybe worth considering another db or a different way of approaching your models design?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoengine works like a charm, you can access your documents as if they were part of the django ORM. You can check it here:

[MongoEngine @ djangopackages.com](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/mongoengine/)

And its documentation: [MongoEngine @ readthedocs.org](http://mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend going thgrough this presentation:

http://staltz.github.io/djangoconfi-mongoengine